# USB Devices not working. PS/2 is working

Tags: windows-8.1, peripherals

Currently navigating round windows only using my keyboard.

I have been using Linux for the past couple of weeks (all the ports work fine there and on the bios) but when I boot into windows they all stop working.

in device manager it shows three Unknown devices within the "Other Devices" but I only have 2 connected (ps2 keyboard which is showing up fine under 'keyboards' and a mouse)

I connect to the Internet via a USB wireless adapter so I am unable to pull down and driver updates either.

I have no restore points either...

Please help me out with this I'm all out of ideas (tried turning off xhci in bios etc but that didn't work).

Any help would be appreciated... Sorry if I explained it badly also, it seems to be a pretty unique situation.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this just got fixed after I managed to navigate through and pull down the latest windows updates (had to share internet with my laptop over an ethernet cable) and they seemed to fix it.

It seemed to be a Windows Update around the 31st August that broke it. But that day I had a power cut as well (even though the computer was off) that might have had an effect?

Anybody with problems in the future:

ps/2 keyboard > naviagte to windows updates > pull down the latest > restart